# <br> &#10 &#xa inside <h:commandButton value> not interpreted as linebreak

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jsf

I have the following problem, i have a JSF command button:

```
<h:commandButton value="#{o.foo}" actionListener="#{someAction}" styleClass="#{row.buttonCssStyle} buttonMenu ">
    <f:attribute name="smthing" value="#{o.smthing}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

This renders as expected[image]

(Sorry for text removal)
But the commandButtons which have  ( as last char on a line do NOT linebreak and i dont know how to solve it. We are talking about IE 9

[image]

Command buttons generated  css:

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks

edit:

from ie debugger:

```
<input name="formId:we:_idJsp112:_idJsp113:3:_idJsp115" class="missingDatesButtonState buttonMenu " id="formId:afterSales:_idJsp112:_idJsp113:3:_idJsp115" onclick="..." type="submit" _nodup="30804" value="TESTST(RL, EBO und SLP)  ( <br/>( (  ( ( ( ( ( asda  #### # # # ### # ( asda"/>
```

Edit @BalusC:
This is the result with line feed:

[image]

I consider it is a failure of the IE9 on parsing of the value , when generating the element... since it works for text but not for symbols... I think it is directly related to that....

Comment: What HTML is generated?

Comment: Added the html, do you have any idea

Comment: buttons cannot have html in them

Comment: @Kukeltje but not even new lines? the br tag wasjust a desperate  attempt...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML code inside HTML attributes isn't interpeted as HTML. [This isn't a JSF problem](http://htmldog.com/guides/html/).

Just insert a real [linefeed character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000a/index.htm) either via `&#xa;` or `&#10;` in (X)HTML or i18n bundle file,

```
<h:commandButton ... value="top line &#xa; bottom line" />
```

... or via `\n` in Java.

```
<h:commandButton ... value="#{bean.value}" />
```

```
value = "top line \n bottom line";
```

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, for the advice, but it isn't working... :( , see my last edit :)

Comment: Sorry I overlooked you seem to have hardcoded  it in the model (which is rather strange, by the way, better put it in a i18n bundle file). See updated answer.

Comment: i wanted just to test it, i leave now but i will come with a feedback asap